# Browser macros through batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, browser, scripting, automation

I want to automate browser actions, like opening a url, logging in and filling a form and then submitting.
I have tried using the iMacros which is a browser extension, but it doesnt work properly.
Also i dont want to use complex tools like Sahi,QTOP or Selenium as this script would be run by more than 150 users on their machines.

My question is whether we can acheive this by just a batch scripting file, (i just tried to open ie through script but after that nothing) if yes then how and if no then what are other simple options for this.

Comment: while this is a "too broad" question, you may want to look at [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)

Comment: You can use batch and iMacros. There is a tutorial about that on wiki imacros.